# Why Friend Function cannot access private members of a class

Tags: c++, class, friend-function

```
class A{
public:
    void printer(){
        B obj;
        obj.private_data = 10; // <- fails, says member inaccessible
    }
}
class B{
friend void A::printer();
private:
    int private_data;
}
```

is it possible for printer function to access private members of class B? i tried to pass an obj of B as arg to printer but it still failed

Comment: I believe the _recommended edit_ was for one of the answers - not your question.  On that assumption, I'm rolling your edit back.

Comment: The code in the question did not produce the error message that's paraphrased in the comment. The code won't compile because at `B obj;` there is no `B`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why Friend Function cannot access private members of a class?

They can, but you may need to split the definition of the class up a bit.

Imaginary files added:

Define `A` (file `a.hpp`):

```
class A {
public:
    void printer();
};
```

Define `B` (file `b.hpp`):

```
#include "a.hpp" // B must see the definition of A to befriend a member function

class B {
    friend void A::printer();

private:
    int private_data;
};
```

Define `A`'s member function (file `a.cpp`):

```
void A::printer() {
    B obj;

    obj.private_data = 10;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Class `A` doesn't know about `B` to use it. Hence, postpone the definition of the function `printer()` until you define `B`, and if you need an instance of `B` to be a member var in `A` then make a forward declaration for `B` to declare a `B*` in `A`.

Hence, use something like what follows:

```cpp
class A {
  public:
    void printer();
};

class B {
    friend void A::printer();

  private:
    int private_data;
};

void A::printer() {
    B obj;
    obj.private_data = 10; // <- No longer fails
    std::cout << obj.private_data;
}

int main() {
    A a;
    a.printer();
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/f4nKs8b5P)

Answer (score 3):

To access `B`, you first need to define it. Thus, you can just *declare* the method `printer` and *define* it after you have defined the class `B`.

```
class A {
public:
  void printer();
};

class B {
private:
  friend class A;
  int private_data;
};

void A::printer() {
  B obj;
  obj.private_data = 10;
}
```

Note, you probably want to move your methods out of your class definition anyways and into a separate `.cpp` file. Methods defined inside the class are implicitly marked as `inline` which might not be what you expect.